# How Do I Connect Stomp Client to An ActiveMQ Artemis Destination Created Using JMS(Spring Boot)?

Tags: jms, spring-jms, stomp, activemq-artemis

## CONTEXT

I am trying to learn about SpringJMS and MOMS and I am using ActiveMQ Artemis for this. I created a Queue Destination address using the `jakarta.jms.*` API, and managed to send some message to the queue like this:

```
public void createUserDestination(String userId) throws JMSException {
        queueDestination = setupConnection().createQueue("user" + userId);
        producer = session.createProducer(queueDestination);
        producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
        producer.send(session.createTextMessage("Testing queue availability"));

        connection.close();
        log.info("successfully created group... going back to controller");
}
```

So for example, if I pass an ID of *user12345abc*, I get a Queue Address `user12345abc`, of the  routing type **ANYCAST** with one queue underneath(with that same address) with my message placed there.

## PROBLEM

Now, I wanted to write a simple web front-end with STOMP that can connect to this queue. But I have been having a ton of problems connecting to that queue address because each time I try to connect by providing the destination address, it creates a new address in the MOM and connects to that instead.
My STOMP code looks like this(the first argument is the destination address, you can ignore the rest of the code):

```
stompClient.subscribe("jms.queue.user12345abc", (message) => {
               receivedMessages.value.push(message.body);
 });
```

In this case, completely brand new queue is created with the address **jms.queue.user12345abc** which is not what I want at all.
I configured my Spring Backend to use an external MOM broker like this(I know this is important):

```
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        // these two end points are prefixes for where the messages are pushed to
        registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("jms.topic", "jms.queue")
            .setRelayHost("127.0.0.1")
            .setRelayPort(61613)
            .setSystemLogin(brokerUsername)
            .setSystemPasscode(brokerPassword)
            .setClientLogin(brokerUsername)
            .setClientPasscode(brokerPassword);

        // this prefixes the end points where clients send messages
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app", "jms.topic", "jms.queue");

        // this prefixes the end points where the user's subscribe to
        registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
}
```

But it's still not working as I expect it to. Am I getting some concept wrong here? How do I use STOMP to connect to that queue I created earlier with JMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you are using the `jms.queue` and `jms.topic` prefixes. Those are similar but not quite the same as the `jms.queue.` and `jms.topic.` prefixes which were used way back in ActiveMQ Artemis 1.x (whose last release was in early 2018 almost 5 years ago now).

In any case, I recommend you use the more widely adopted `/queue/` and `/topic/`, e.g.:

```java
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    // these two end points are prefixes for where the messages are pushed to
    registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic/", "/queue/")
            .setRelayHost("127.0.0.1")
            .setRelayPort(61613)
            .setSystemLogin(brokerUsername)
            .setSystemPasscode(brokerPassword)
            .setClientLogin(brokerUsername)
            .setClientPasscode(brokerPassword);

    // this prefixes the end points where clients send messages
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app", "/topic/", "/queue/");

    // this prefixes the end points where the user's subscribe to
    registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
}
```

The in `broker.xml` you'd need to add the corresponding `anycastPrefix` and `multicastPrefix` values on the STOMP `acceptor`, e.g.:

```xml
<acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true;anycastPrefix=/queue/;multicastPrefix=/topic/</acceptor>
```

To be clear, your JMS code will stay the same, but your STOMP consumer would be something like:

```java
stompClient.subscribe("/queue/user12345abc", (message) => {
               receivedMessages.value.push(message.body);
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this does not seem to be working. I have never used a broker.xml before, so I am wondering where the file goes. Also, the MOM instance I am using is not embedded, I am using an external one. So does the broker.xml only work with the embedded instance? PS: If you could give me a basic template for the xml file it would be great

Comment: The file `broker.xml` contains main configuration for ActiveMQ Artemis. If you are running a standalone (i.e. not embedded) instance of ActiveMQ Artemis then you can find your `broker.xml` in the `etc` directory of the broker instance.

Comment: Your suggestion actually worked. I had to re-install Artemis though correctly using the information on this site [Install ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.3.0/using-server.html) then simply update the STOMP acceptor and it all just worked. Including the durable STOMP subscription. Thank you so much.